# Banning special characters in search form input

Tags: search

Apologies if this is a duplicate posting, I've searched extensively and cannot find either this question or a solution, or even to know if this is really a problem.

I find a LOT of search queries performed on my site where the person or bot is searching for terms like "index/\think\app/invokefunction" and other similar terms.  There are obviously no results shown, but the quantity of these searches are overwhelming my search logs, which I use to help me improve my site's content and SEO.

I would ideally like to just ban all special characters (such as / \ ? [] et al) from the search form input field.

So my questions are:

- is this a potentially security-related problem I should be concerned
  about?
- can I ban such characters in the search form?
- if so, how?

I am not a classically-trained coder but I am very good at following instructions!

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Note that bots don't use the search input, bots trying to use exploits don't even bother to check if you're using WordPress, they just fire off the HTTP request, and if their payload works it sends a message back. You could remove your search box completely and it wouldn't stop these. Instead I would focus on making sure you don't log searches from bots, you'll need to look at how you're logging, not the search input or frontend HTML

Comment: Thank you Tom - that is helpful.....I use MWT: Search Analytics for the logging so I'll poke around there..... Muchas gracias!